# Saving variable in Rdata file with string in variable name

Tags: r

I have a vector `a=0.01`

Then I create a `mat<-matrix(data=NA,ncol=10,nrow=10)`

I rename the matrix by:

```
assign(x = paste("mat", a, sep = "_"), value = mat)
```

The resulting variable will be called `mat_0.01`

Then I would like to save this variable:

```
save(mat_'string', file="mat.Rdata")
```

The question is how to pass the new variable name in the save argument.

Comment: `assign` is the wrong approach. Store your data into a list, e.g. `simulation <- list(a = a, mat = mat)`. If you have many of these, store them in a list of lists.

Comment: I could not agree more with @flodel.

Comment: this can get really messy, after I while how do I know which vector belongs to which matrix?

Comment: You'd have a collection of objects. Where each objects contains its own `a` and `mat`. That's the opposite of messy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation of `assign` suggests to use `get` to do the reverse lookup (see the examples at the end):

```
> a = 1
> get('a')
[1] 1
```

To use it with `save`:

```
to_be_saved_obj = paste("mat", a, sep = "_")
save(list = to_be_saved_obj, file = 'mat.Rdata')
```